# how to send string data to the angularjs app using grunt cli?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I'm using [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) to setup my angularjs application and `grunt` as my task runner.

I need to send `baseurl` to my `service` so that i dynamically set the `baseurl` to my APIEndpoints.

`grunt serve baseurl:'http:111.111.11.11'`

Is there any way to do so using grunt cli ?

Any help is highly appreciated.. thanks in advance